# Original data Altman used for his z-score formula

Tags: data-request, financial-economics, corporate-finance

At our university we are researching the usefulness of failing (bankrupticy) prediction models. We are interested in the original datasets [Altman](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/ealtman/) used for his models. Does anyone know where this datasets can be found?
We have the same question for the datasets [Ohlson](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~johlson/) used.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Ed. Altman or Jim Ohlson? They are both still working.

Answer (score 1):

The original paper (of Altman) is

[Altman, E. I. (1968). Financial ratios, discriminant analysis and the prediction of corporate bankruptcy. The journal of finance, 23(4), 589-609.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1968.tb00843.x/pdf)

We read (p. 593)

> **III. DEVELOPMENT OF THE MODEL**
>
> "**Sample Selection.** The initial sample is composed of sixty-six
>   corporations with thirty-three firms in each of the two groups. The
>   bankrupt group (Group 1) are manufacturers that filed a bankruptcy
>   petition under Chapter X of the National Bankruptcy Act during the
>   period 1946-1965. (...) Recognizing that this group is not completely
>   homogeneous, due to industry and size differences, a careful selection
>   of non-bankrupt firms was attempted. Group 2 consisted of a paired
>   sample of manufacturing firms chosen on a stratified random basis.
>   (...) Firms in Group 2 were still in existence in 1966. Also, the data
>   collected are from the same years as those compiled for the bankrupt
>   firms. For the initial sample test, the data are derived from
>   financial statements one reporting period prior to bankruptcy.
>   (footnote 18: The data was derived from Moody's Industrial Manuals and
>   selected Annual Reports. The average lead time of the financial
>   statements was approximately seven and one-half months prior to
>   bankruptcy.)

The paper does not contain, even in print form, the actual data sample, so BKay's suggestion to contact the authors is your best shot.